# Jquery Count-up timer

Tags: jquery, html, date, time

I'm trying to insert into my html a counter (only hours, minutes, and seconds) - that starts at 2 hours 2 min 0 sec when you open the web page, and then counts up.

How do I get this code to not start at 0 but at 02:02:00 ?
How do I get the hours displayed in a single digit if they are <10 ?

(I would ideally like to add a feature for the timer to restart where it left off if you ever come back on the page.)

Any ideas..?
Thanks!

```
$().ready(function(){
    var startYear = new Date()        
      $('#Hours').countdown({since: startYear, compact:true,
    format: 'H', description: ' Hours'});   
    $('#Min').countdown({since: startYear, compact:true,
    format: 'MS', description: ' Minutes and seconds'});  
})
```

And then within the html:

```
<div id="Min"></div><div id="Hours"></div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest viewing your variable `startYear` and seeing how you should edit it.  `Date();` returns the date and time.

Comment: what is this coutdown function? can you provide the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can set any of the month/year/day/hours.. like this:

```
var startYear = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: like this?
Date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546")  
The code doesn't work with this.. :/